# Issue creating QueryDSL Predicate from a Java Object having a List field

Tags: java, spring, querydsl, predicate

Having the following request class receiving :

```
public class WRequest{
    Integer Id        
    String name;
    List<Integer> RelatedIds;
}
```

I try to build a queryDsl predicate in order to pass it to spring data findAll() method:

```
BooleanBuilder builder = new BooleanBuilder();
Optional.ofNullable(wrequest.getId())
        .map(QWRequest.wrequest.id::eq).ifPresent(builder::and);
Optional.ofNullable(wrequest.getName())
        .map(QWRequest.wrequest.name::eq).ifPresent(builder::and);
```

The above snippet of code works only for String/Integer paramters, however I am unable to build the Predicate to include in the results any of the values in the RelatedIds List. How to create a QueryDSL predicate from an object that has a List field?

**QWRequest** class is the autogenerated QueryDSL query type from for the Wrequest class.

Comment: The question is a bit vague, but do you perhaps mean `.map(QWRequest.wrequest.relatedIds.any()::eq)`? Or perhaps `.map(QWRequest.wrequest.relatedIds::contains)`?